# organize reactivity with pre-loaded data

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, shiny-reactivity

I have couple of tables stored each in a separate txt file, and also combined in a single Rdat file, something like this:

```
# generate tables
df.A <- data.frame(colA1=letters[1:20],colA2=LETTERS[1:20], stringsAsFactors = F)
df.B <- data.frame(colB1=rnorm(20),colB2=rnorm(20), stringsAsFactors = F)

# save tables as separate files
write.csv(df.A, 'tableA.txt')
write.csv(df.B, 'tableB.txt')
# I may have more tables

# save all tables in a single Rdat file
save(df.A,df.B, file = 'alldata.RDat')
```

Now in my shiny markdown document, I want to pre-load those tables from the `RDat` file, but also give user a possibility to re-load them a) separately from individual files, or b) altogether from the RDat file. Here is the first version I came to:

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
load('alldata.RDat')
```

Tables below:
```{r}
inputPanel(
  actionButton('load.A','Reload Table A'),
  actionButton('load.B','Reload Table B'),
  actionButton('load.Rdat','Load all from Rdat file')
)

 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("table A", dataTableOutput("toA")),
                  tabPanel("table B", dataTableOutput("toB"))
      )

 # next 2 lines render pre-loaded tables before any buttons are pressed:
 output$toA  <- renderDataTable(df.A, options=list(pageLength=5))
 output$toB  <- renderDataTable(df.B, options=list(pageLength=5))

 observeEvent(input$load.A, {
   df.A <- read.csv('tableA.txt'); 
   output$toA  <- renderDataTable(df.A, options=list(pageLength=5))
   })

 observeEvent(input$load.B, {
   df.B <- read.csv('tableB.txt'); 
   output$toB  <- renderDataTable(df.B, options=list(pageLength=5))
   })

 observeEvent(input$load.Rdat, {
   load('alldata.RDat', verbose = T);
   output$toA  <- renderDataTable(df.A, options=list(pageLength=5));
   output$toB  <- renderDataTable(df.B, options=list(pageLength=5))
 })

```
````

It works fine, but I have a feeling it is not the proper way to use reactivity. For example, every time after updating my table object (`df.A` or `dfB`), I have to call render explicitly `output$toA  <- renderDataTable(...)` (3 times for each table!).

One solution I had in mind was to put my tables into `reactiveValues()`, which gave the following:

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
load('alldata.RDat')
```

Tables below:
```{r}
inputPanel(
  actionButton('load.A','Reload Table A'),
  actionButton('load.B','Reload Table B'),
  actionButton('load.Rdat','Load all from Rdat file')
)

 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("table A", dataTableOutput("toA")),
                  tabPanel("table B", dataTableOutput("toB"))
      )

 rv <- reactiveValues(df.A = df.A, df.B = df.B)

 output$toA  <- renderDataTable(rv$df.A, options=list(pageLength=5))
 output$toB  <- renderDataTable(rv$df.B, options=list(pageLength=5))

 observeEvent(input$load.A, {
   rv$df.A <- read.csv('tableA.txt'); 
   })

 observeEvent(input$load.B, {
   rv$df.B <- read.csv('tableB.txt'); 
   })

 observeEvent(input$load.Rdat, {
   load('alldata.RDat', verbose = T);
   rv$df.A <- df.A;
   rv$df.B <- df.B;
 })

```
````

This looks better because I have only one call of each `renderDataTable()` in my code. But now each of my tables are stored in memory twice - one in `df.A` (as loaded from 'alldata.RDat') and another one in `rv$df.A`... Does it make sense at all, or there's a more kosher way to solve these kinds of things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to load the data for `df.A` and `df.B` from either a csv or `Rdat` file. This almost certainly requires an intermediate variable, `rv` as you have correctly created.

The second example you have created is much better than the first, we must avoid multiple render calls to the same `output`, especially render calls inside an observer.

The code below executes `load('alldata.RDat', verbose = T)` from within the observer and the initial values of `rv` are set from within the observer instead of using the global `load('alldata.RDat', verbose = T)`. This prevents the data from being loaded twice.

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
#load('alldata.RDat')
```

Tables below:
```{r}
inputPanel(
  actionButton('load.A','Reload Table A'),
  actionButton('load.B','Reload Table B'),
  actionButton('load.Rdat','Load all from Rdat file')
)

 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("table A", dataTableOutput("toA")),
                  tabPanel("table B", dataTableOutput("toB"))
      )

 rv <- reactiveValues(df.A = NULL, df.B = NULL)

 output$toA  <- renderDataTable({
   req(rv$df.A)
   rv$df.A
   }, options=list(pageLength=5))

 output$toB  <- renderDataTable({
   req(rv$df.B)
   rv$df.B
   }, options=list(pageLength=5))

 observeEvent(input$load.A, {
   rv$df.A <- read.csv('tableA.txt'); 
   })

 observeEvent(input$load.B, {
   rv$df.B <- read.csv('tableB.txt'); 
   })

 observeEvent(c(input$load.Rdat), {
   load('alldata.RDat', verbose = T);
   rv$df.A <- df.A;
   rv$df.B <- df.B;
 })
```
````

Comment: thank you @Sada93! Sorry for my ignorance - could you elaborate why do we need calls like `req(rv$df.A)`? I checked what happens if I remove those two calls and it seems to work the same way...

Comment: Another question - how does wrapping `input$load.Rdat` into `c()` work in `observeEvent()`? I understand that it triggers the code to load even if the button `load.Rdat` was not pressed - but how it makes this difference?

Comment: The `req()` is just a force of habit to ensure the values exist before proceeding. You may remove them but it's safe to keep them there. With respect to your second question... unfortunately, I don't understand the mechanics of it. I also don't know if this is the intended behavior of the authors of shiny. Do you mind if I use a modified version of this example to open an issue on github?

Comment: of course, go ahead! I was thinking to post it as a question here at SO, but if you think it's worth a GH issue - why not.